# Problem with an algorithm to $3$-colour the edges of cubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matlab

I'm currently trying to implement an algorithm to $3$-colour the edges of cubic graphs. 
(I want to do this with Matlab's Symbolic toolbox). After restricting to planar graphs to ensure the existence of a solution, I tried the following:

First, I observed that once a colouring is found the adjacency matrix $A$ split into three matrices with the following properties:

- $\hskip-5.0in A_1+A_2+A_3=A \tag{1}$
- $\hskip-5.0in A_k^2=1, \tag{2} $

where $1$ is the unit matrix and the idea is related to the concept of [$1$-factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-factorization) I think...

So I tried the following:

1. I set up matrices $X=(x_{kl})\odot A$, where $\odot$ is the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) ($Y$ and $Z$ accordingly),
2. plugged them into $(1)$ and $(2)$,
3. let the computer solve the set of equations
4. received some promising results for small dimensions (less than $10$)
5. and some frustating for larger ones (more than $20$).

I tried to use facts like, all entries in $A_k$ are either $0$ or $1$, so squares of certain variables in $(2)$ could be written as linear terms as well.

So my question is:

> Is there a principle problem with this approach? Which other **mathematical** tricks can I use?

Comment: Have you read about snarks? These are precisely the cubic graphs that are not 3-edge-colorable and hence your problem is in a way equivalent to recognizing snarks.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: @Jernej I have, and therefore I tried examples where I knew a $3$-edge-colouring in advance, i.e. planar cubic graphs...In other words: No snarks, please...

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/complexity-of-edge-coloring-in-planar-graphs , which appears to cover precisely this question.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki great link, thanks...